# GPT-4-0613 Finish_Reason Null Issue in Streaming Mode

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api, azure-openai

I am facing an issue while using the latest **OpenAI GPT-4-0613** models in **streaming mode**. Specifically, I have noticed that for some cases, the `finish_reason` field in the response comes as Null instead of the expected value `'stop'` for the last token. I have provided the necessary context along with my question in the prompt.
Similar Question is asked in Openai Forum: https://community.openai.com/t/completion-finish-reason-is-missing-when-stream-true/90526

Following code:

```
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model='gpt-4-0613',
    messages=[
        {'role': 'user', 'content': "Context along with question"}
    ],
    temperature=0,
    stream=True 
)

for chunk in response:
    print(chunk)
```

My understanding is that the finish_reason field should indicate 'stop' for the last token when using the streaming mode. However, in certain cases, it appears to be Null. This behavior seems inconsistent with the expected behavior of the model.

**Notice**: However, `gpt-0314` always gives finish_reason as `stop` for last token

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any updates on that?